# Ruby assertions and disabled inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, testunit, webrat

Does anyone know how to assert that a checkbox or input is disabled?  I can't find anything to indicated that this is supported
I'm writing cucumber tests with webrat and test/unit.

I'd like to have a step that is able to assert_disabled :some_checkbox || assert_disabled :some_input.

Or some way that I can check a property of the checkbox.

Comment: i guess no one read that I'm using test/unit

Answer (score 4):

```
Then /^the "([^\"]*)" field should be disabled$/ do |label|
  field_labeled(label).should be_disabled
end
```

should do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

This probably wont help you with Webrat and Test/Unit, but for people using Capybara, you can use

```
Then /^the "([^\"]+)" field should be disabled$/ do |field|
  find_field(field)[:disabled].should == 'disabled'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a go:

```
Then /^the "([^\"]*)" field should be disabled$/ do |label|
  field_labeled(label)['disabled'].should == true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got Pete's answer to work but had to switch to field_with_id.

```
field_with_id(label).should be_disabled
```